# MBProgressHUD added to navigationController.view without disabling userInteraction

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uinavigationcontroller, mbprogresshud

I have to add my MBProgressHUD to `self.navigationController.view` because on `self.view` there is a design bug (in `UITableView`).

Everything works as expected, but MBProgressHud disable the userInteraction on the back button (left `navigationItem`) and I would like that doesn't disable this.

How can I make it ?

Here is a screenshot when I add hud to `self.view`:
[image: screenshot]

Comment: did u try changing the hud frame ?

Comment: @TejaNandamuri when I'm adding to self.view ? No. What do you mean ? I'm using:     self.hud = [MBProgressHUD showHUDAddedTo:self.view animated:YES];
    self.hud.mode = MBProgressHUDModeIndeterminate;

Comment: @TejaNandamuri tried to change frame, doesn't work...

Comment: How did u change it ?

Comment: @TejaNandamuri tried with     self.hud = [MBProgressHUD showHUDAddedTo:self.view animated:YES];
    self.hud.frame = CGRectMake(200, 200, 50, 50);

Comment: Why don't you explain in detail why you can't add it to the child view controller of the navigation controller?

Comment: @Avi I have updated my post, please see the screenshot. I have already tried to add to self.navigationController.childViewControllers.lastObject.view. Still the same design bug ;)

Answer (score 1):

You can embed your UITableViewController in a ContainerView then show the HUD on the Container.

Answer (score 0):

Nice workaround, add:

```
self.hud.layer.zPosition = 2;
self.tableView.layer.zPosition = 1;
```